# How can I remove options from a select using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here:

```
function onAjaxDone(data) {
    var topicID;

    $('#TopicID')
        .html(data);

    topicID = store.getItem('TopicID');
    if (topicID) {
        $("#TopicID")
            .val(topicID);
        $('option[value="88"]', this).remove();
        $('option[value="99"]', this).remove();
    }
}
```

I get an error saying "failed strict" and pointing to the lines with "this".  What I want to do is to remove the option lines with a value of 88 and 99 for the select element with id of TopicID. Am I coding this wrong? This was an example given to me but I am not sure why the "this" is there on those two lines.

Comment: I can't be sure because I don't know the markup of your html data, but you are specifying a context ('this'), which is the result of 'store.getItem('TopicID'). I don't know what this produces, html?

Comment: "What I want to do is to remove the option lines with a value of 88 and 99 for the select element with id of TopicID" 

Both options have the same `id`? that's a mistake there, also `this` won't get you `TopicID` as it's not used in the right context.

Also `this` is wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function onAjaxDone(data) {
    var topicID, selTopic;

    selTopic = $('#TopicID');
    selTopic.html(data);

    topicID = store.getItem('TopicID');
    if (topicID) {
        selTopic.val(topicID);
        $('option[value="88"]', selTopic).remove();
        $('option[value="99"]', selTopic).remove();
        //or
        //selTopic.val(topicID)
        //.find('option[value="88"]').remove().end()
        //.find('option[value="99"]').remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from the jQuery documentation

```
jQuery( selector [, context] )
  selector: A string containing a selector expression
  context: A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context
```

This means that that the *this* you used is supposed to point to one of the DOM elements whose children are the two options, but obviously it does not.

you should change it to something like

```
$('option[value="88"]', el).remove();
$('option[value="99"]', el).remove();
```

where *el* is the form or select or whatever parent element of

```
<option value='88'></option>
<option value='89'></option>
```

or if you're sure you will have **only** two options with those values in your entire webpage, then you can just do

```
$('option[value="88"]').remove();
$('option[value="99"]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#TopicID option[value='88']").remove();
$("#TopicID option[value='89']").remove();
```